# In the windows or Linux what IDE can be compared with XCODE

Tags: xcode, ide

Yesterday I use the XCODE in MAC OS , find this IDE really good strong. So I would like to ask In the windows or Linux what IDE can be compared with XCODE

Comment: It depends on your requirements. Do you need to code in Swift/Objective-C? Or C/C++?

Answer (score 0):

I think an excellent IDE for windows is Visual Studio. Then other good IDE are eclipse and netbeans and run on windows, Linux and Mac.
This is only my opinion!

Answer (score 0):

- The go-to IDE on Windows is [Visual Studio](http://www.visualstudio.com).
- [Eclipse](https://eclipse.org) and [NetBeans](https://netbeans.org) are other popular choices that also support Linux.

Comment: But for example NetBeans on OS X is nowhere near as effective as Xcode.